# UIScrollView is not scrolling after end of screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to work with UIScrollView which I am adding programatically with auto layouts. I read other SO answers but none of them is working for me. My ScollView is scrolling but upto some point. After that end of the last child view is not showing. What i did was ,added a contentView to the UIScrollView and added subviews to the contentView. All the subviews are 
**translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false** which is supposed t give me contentSize based on the constraints of the views but it is not. I tried locking the bottom of the contentView to the scrollview and also the bottom of the last subview of the contentview to the scrollview but it not working. Basically there are **cards** in the contentView which has **height** constraints. But they are not scrolling to the end. Last child is not scrolled to the end no matter what I do. What can be wrong with this approach?

```
class NodeSettingViewController: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var scrollView:UIScrollView?
    var cellVM:NodeAppCellViewModel?
    var contentView:UIView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let img = UIImage(named: "back_arrow")
        let size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        img!.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(closeButtonTapped(_:)))

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        let appBar = MDCAppBarViewController()
        appBar.headerStackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex: Constants.color)
        appBar.navigationBar.titleAlignment = .center
        appBar.navigationBar.titleTextColor = UIColor.white
        appBar.navigationBar.backItem = backButton
        appBar.navigationBar.title = cellVM!.appName == nil ? "" : cellVM!.appName!

        view.addSubview(appBar.view)


        scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false

        contentView = UIView()
        contentView!.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex: Constants.BACKGROUUND_COLOR)

        contentView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false

        let statusAndImageHolder = StatusAndImageHolderView()
        statusAndImageHolder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        statusAndImageHolder.setup(cellVM: cellVM)
        contentView!.addSubview(statusAndImageHolder)

        let healthCard = HealthCard()
        healthCard.setShadowElevation(ShadowElevation.cardResting, for: UIControlState.normal)
        healthCard.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        healthCard.setup(hubID: cellVM!.nodeApp!.hubId!, nodeID: cellVM!.nodeApp!.nodeId!,nApp: cellVM!.nodeApp)

        let upperConstaintHealthCard = NSLayoutConstraint(item: healthCard, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: contentView!.subviews[contentView!.subviews.count-1], attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant:10)
        let leftConstraintHealthCard = NSLayoutConstraint(item: healthCard, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        let rightConstraintHealthCard = NSLayoutConstraint(item: healthCard, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, multiplier: 1, constant: -10)
        let heightConstraintHealthCard = NSLayoutConstraint(item: healthCard, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 150)

        contentView!.addSubview(healthCard)


        let additionalInfoCard = AdditionalInformationCard()
        additionalInfoCard.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        additionalInfoCard.setShadowElevation(ShadowElevation.cardResting, for: UIControlState.normal)
        additionalInfoCard.setup()

        let upperConstaintAdditionalInfoCard = NSLayoutConstraint(item: additionalInfoCard, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: contentView!.subviews[contentView!.subviews.count-1], attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant:10)
        let leftConstraintAdditionalInfoCard = NSLayoutConstraint(item: additionalInfoCard, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        let rightConstraintAdditionalInfoCard = NSLayoutConstraint(item: additionalInfoCard, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, multiplier: 1, constant: -10)
        let heightConstraintAdditionalInfoCard = NSLayoutConstraint(item: additionalInfoCard, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 270)

        contentView!.addSubview(additionalInfoCard)

        let upperConstaintHolder = NSLayoutConstraint(item: statusAndImageHolder, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant:0)
        let leftConstraintHolder = NSLayoutConstraint(item: statusAndImageHolder, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let rightConstraintHolder = NSLayoutConstraint(item: statusAndImageHolder, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, multiplier: 1, constant: -0)
        let heightConstraintHolder = NSLayoutConstraint(item: statusAndImageHolder, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 150)

        scrollView!.addSubview(contentView!)
        scrollView!.bringSubview(toFront: contentView!)

        self.view.addSubview(scrollView!)

        let contentSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let contentHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height-30

        let upperConstaintScrollView = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: appBar.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let leftConstraintScrollView = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let rightConstraintScrollView = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, multiplier: 1, constant: -0)
        let bottomConstraintScrollView = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -0)

        let upperConstaintContentView = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: scrollView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let leftConstraintContentView = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: scrollView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let widthConstraintContentView = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: contentSize)
        let heightConstraintContentView = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: contentHeight)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([upperConstaintScrollView,leftConstraintScrollView,rightConstraintScrollView,bottomConstraintScrollView,upperConstaintContentView,leftConstraintContentView,widthConstraintContentView,heightConstraintContentView,
                    upperConstaintHolder,leftConstraintHolder,rightConstraintHolder,heightConstraintHolder,
                    upperConstaintHealthCard,leftConstraintHealthCard,rightConstraintHealthCard,heightConstraintHealthCard,upperConstaintAdditionalInfoCard,leftConstraintAdditionalInfoCard,rightConstraintAdditionalInfoCard,heightConstraintAdditionalInfoCard])
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    @objc func closeButtonTapped(_ sender:Any){
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        scrollView?.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
        scrollView!.isScrollEnabled=true
        scrollView!.delegate=self
        scrollView!.contentSize = contentView!.frame.size
    }
}
```

I am sharing one of my card which is the last child of the subview.

```
class AdditionalInformationCard: MDCCard {

    var titleLabel:UILabel?
    var placeIdLabel:UILabel?
    var eIDLabel:UILabel?
    var hubIdLabel:UILabel?
    var parentIDLabel:UILabel?
    var deviceAddressLabel:UILabel?
    var appIDLabel:UILabel?
    var firmwareVersionLabel:UILabel?
    var addedOnLabel:UILabel?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    func setup(){

        let cardWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width-20
        let contentWidth = cardWidth-20

        titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
        titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor(netHex: Constants.color)
        titleLabel?.textAlignment = .left
        titleLabel?.text = "Additional Information"
        titleLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false

        self.addSubview(titleLabel!)

        placeIdLabel = UILabel()
        placeIdLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray
        placeIdLabel?.text = "Place Id"
        placeIdLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false

        self.addSubview(placeIdLabel!)

        eIDLabel = UILabel()
        eIDLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray
        eIDLabel?.text = "eId"
        eIDLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false

        self.addSubview(eIDLabel!)

        hubIdLabel = UILabel()
        hubIdLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray
        hubIdLabel?.text = "HUB Id"
        hubIdLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false

        self.addSubview(hubIdLabel!)

        parentIDLabel = UILabel()
        parentIDLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray
        parentIDLabel?.text = "Parent Id"
        parentIDLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false

        self.addSubview(parentIDLabel!)

        deviceAddressLabel = UILabel()
        deviceAddressLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray
        deviceAddressLabel?.text = "Device Address"
        deviceAddressLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false

        self.addSubview(deviceAddressLabel!)

        appIDLabel = UILabel()
        appIDLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray
        appIDLabel?.text = "App Id"
        appIDLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false

        self.addSubview(appIDLabel!)

        firmwareVersionLabel = UILabel()
        firmwareVersionLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray
        firmwareVersionLabel?.text = "Firmware Version"
        firmwareVersionLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false

        self.addSubview(firmwareVersionLabel!)

        addedOnLabel = UILabel()
        addedOnLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray
        addedOnLabel?.text = "Added On"
        addedOnLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false

        self.addSubview(addedOnLabel!)



        let upperConstraintTitle = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 5)
        let leftConstraintTitle = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        let rightConstraintTitle = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        let heightConstraintTitle = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)

        let upperConstraintPlaceId = NSLayoutConstraint(item: placeIdLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: titleLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        let leftConstraintPlaceId = NSLayoutConstraint(item: placeIdLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        let widthConstraintPlaceId = NSLayoutConstraint(item: placeIdLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: contentWidth/2)
        let heightConstraintPlaceId = NSLayoutConstraint(item: placeIdLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)

        let upperConstrainteId = NSLayoutConstraint(item: eIDLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: placeIdLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
        let leftConstrainteId = NSLayoutConstraint(item: eIDLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        let widthConstrainteId = NSLayoutConstraint(item: eIDLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: contentWidth/2)
        let heightConstrainteId = NSLayoutConstraint(item: eIDLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)

        let upperConstraintHubIdLabel = NSLayoutConstraint(item: hubIdLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: eIDLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
        let leftConstraintHubIdLabel = NSLayoutConstraint(item: hubIdLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        let widthConstraintHubIdLabel = NSLayoutConstraint(item: hubIdLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: contentWidth/2)
        let heightConstraintHubIdLabel = NSLayoutConstraint(item: hubIdLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)

        let upperConstraintParentIdLabel = NSLayoutConstraint(item: parentIDLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: hubIdLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
        let leftConstraintParentIdLabel = NSLayoutConstraint(item: parentIDLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        let widthConstraintParentIdLabel = NSLayoutConstraint(item: parentIDLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: contentWidth/2)
        let heightConstraintParentIdLabel = NSLayoutConstraint(item: parentIDLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)

        let upperConstraintDeiveAddressLabel = NSLayoutConstraint(item: deviceAddressLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: parentIDLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
        let leftConstraintDeiveAddressLabel = NSLayoutConstraint(item: deviceAddressLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        let widthConstraintDeiveAddressLabel = NSLayoutConstraint(item: deviceAddressLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: contentWidth/2)
        let heightConstraintDeiveAddressLabel = NSLayoutConstraint(item: deviceAddressLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)

        let upperConstraintAppId = NSLayoutConstraint(item: appIDLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: deviceAddressLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
        let leftConstraintAppId = NSLayoutConstraint(item: appIDLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        let widthConstraintAppId = NSLayoutConstraint(item: appIDLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: contentWidth/2)
        let heightConstraintAppId = NSLayoutConstraint(item: appIDLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)

        let upperConstraintFirmwareVersion = NSLayoutConstraint(item: firmwareVersionLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: appIDLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
        let leftConstraintFirmwareVersion = NSLayoutConstraint(item: firmwareVersionLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        let widthConstraintFirmwareVersion = NSLayoutConstraint(item: firmwareVersionLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: contentWidth/2)
        let heightConstraintFirmwareVersion = NSLayoutConstraint(item: firmwareVersionLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)

        let upperConstraintAddedOn = NSLayoutConstraint(item: addedOnLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: firmwareVersionLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
        let leftConstraintAddedOn = NSLayoutConstraint(item: addedOnLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        let widthConstraintAddedOn = NSLayoutConstraint(item: addedOnLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: contentWidth/2)
        let heightConstraintAddedOn = NSLayoutConstraint(item: addedOnLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([upperConstraintTitle,leftConstraintTitle,rightConstraintTitle,heightConstraintTitle,
                                     upperConstraintPlaceId,leftConstraintPlaceId,widthConstraintPlaceId,heightConstraintPlaceId,
                                     upperConstrainteId,leftConstrainteId,widthConstrainteId,heightConstrainteId,
                                     upperConstraintHubIdLabel,leftConstraintHubIdLabel,widthConstraintHubIdLabel,heightConstraintHubIdLabel,
                                     upperConstraintParentIdLabel,leftConstraintParentIdLabel,widthConstraintParentIdLabel,heightConstraintParentIdLabel,upperConstraintDeiveAddressLabel,leftConstraintDeiveAddressLabel,widthConstraintDeiveAddressLabel,heightConstraintDeiveAddressLabel,
                                     upperConstraintAppId,leftConstraintAppId,widthConstraintAppId,heightConstraintAppId,
                                     upperConstraintFirmwareVersion,leftConstraintFirmwareVersion,widthConstraintFirmwareVersion,heightConstraintFirmwareVersion,upperConstraintAddedOn,leftConstraintAddedOn,widthConstraintAddedOn,heightConstraintAddedOn])
    }

}
```

Comment: First thing first, don't use scrollview directly use UITableView or UICollectionView

Comment: This is a rewrite of the application and i used uitableview for the first time. but there i faced many issues and it also bloated my view controller which became 4435 lines. thats why I rearchitectured it to use uiscrollview which will be simple for our use case.

Comment: i think your current code is also bloated

Comment: You are facing this issue because of constraints nothing else, to overcome this issue i suggest you to use Table view